# Normal force towards the contacting object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I was solving a problem with this diagram:[image]

All the surfaces are friction-less. When I saw the solution it was considering the normal forces between $M$ and $m2$, but they were heading towards each other.

1. Why is this happening? I think it is because of the pulley, making pendulum when $M$ moves infinitesimal amount.
2. Do we call this a normal force? I've never seen this before but I've seen many examples with opposite direction for example, the ground reaction force.

Comment: Do all objects start from rest or is there some non-zero initial velocity?

Comment: @R. Elder From rest.

Comment: Were the forces an action-reaction pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you got a wrong solution!!

Normal forces come into play only when objects come in contact with each other. And from its name it is quite evident that it is always perpendicular to the surface in contact.

Now, how to decide if we need to apply the normal forces or not? Simple!! Look at the FBDs. In your case, you need to draw the FBD of $M$ (Don't dare to forget the pulley!!). If you clearly observe the horizontal forces acting on $M$, it is only the tension force of the rope directing towards left. Now 'normal' is a support force which will appear only when there is a pressing tendency. So is $M$ pushing $m_2$? Certainly not. As a result normal force will not be present.

Comment: Then what force is present to m2? I think it should accelerate to left.

Comment: There will be no horizontal forces for $m_2$. $M$ will have an acceleration towards left as it has a tension force towards its left. This will give an illusion that $m_2$ is accelerating.

Comment: In case there would have a contact force between $M$ and $m_2$, $m_2$ would also have accelerating with the same acceleration as that of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal situation, there should not be any forces between M and m2 because no forces are physically attracting or repelling m2 and M.

Comment: Do we call attracting perpendicular contact force a normal force too?

Comment: If two bodies are in contact, the contact forces on both the bodies are directed away from the point of contact. I assume that by normal forces you mean normal contact forces. The term is self-explanatory, contact forces that act normal to the surfaces in contact are normal contact forces.